in odoo16 How to hide "section-financials" from the ProductInfoPopup in POS Screen
I'm working on project and I need to remove section from the "ProductInfoPopup" this section is 
"section-financials" and I try to use this code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
     <t t-inherit="point_of_sale.ProductInfoPopup" t-inherit-mode="extension">
         <xpath expr="//div[@class='section-financials']" position="replace">
                <span>----------</span>
         </xpath>
     </t>
</templates>

but It give me errors, I do not know what is the problem
